# Get correct epoch time from client even if time on client is wrong

Tags: javascript, timestamp, countdowntimer, epoch

I am building a real time web app that requires epoch time from client. The calculation is involving a timestamp coming from my server and the timestamp from the client. I use the following code to get the epoch timestamp from client using JS:

```
var milliseconds = Math.floor((new Date).getTime()/1000);
```

JS is client based, so the value retrieved is based on the date/time the client has. So there is a possibility that the client date/time is misconfigured and the epoch time retrieved is wrong.

Is there a way to make sure that the epoch time from client is the correct one? Or is there a way to correct it if wrong?

Sure, i can use AJAX to get the epoch time from server, but since i use that time inside a countdown function, this means i have to hit the server every second..

[The reason i don't add a second to current time in every loop, is because i have problem when a mobile device sleeps. When the mobile device wakes up it starts counting down from where it were when turned off. It will not consider that the current time is increased. ]

Any advice would be appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var getClientMillis = function() {
    return Date.now();
}

var realStartTime = getServerMillis();
var clientStartTime = getClientMillis();

var getCurrentMillis = function() {
    return realStartTime + (getClientMillis() - clientStartTime);
}
```

You need to implement `getServerMillis()` yourself.

Comment: Will getServerMillis () need to poll the server each second? Also the getCurrentMillis will return realStartTime, since getClientMillis () == clientStartTime?

Comment: You only need to poll the server once. `realStartTime` and `clientStartTime` need to be initiated only once, too. `getClientMillis()` will only return a value equal to `clientStartTime` when called at the same millisecond `clientStartTime` was initialized, as `getClientMillis()` will return the client time at the moment it is called.

Comment: Thanks Jaagup! Will test it tomorrow and let you know of the result!